# AWS Cognito hosted UI forgot password code gets sent to NON-registered email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-hosted-ui

I have simple use-case. I can create users **manually** in AWS Cognito. While creating a user, I enter **emailId** (eg. `myemail@gmail.com`) manually and check `Mark email address as verified` checkbox. After creating a user, confirmation status will be **Force Change Password**.

I can change password using **HostedUI**. I open **HostedUI** and click on `**Forgot password**` link, **HostedUI** asks me to enter username, I enter it and it sends email to some other **emailId** (eg m****@y****.com (I don't know from where this Id comes)).

I can confirm that other **emailId** is **NOT the registered emailId** of the user.

**Q:** Why does AWS Cognito send email to non-registered emailId and from where does it pull non-registered emailId ?

**NOTE:** It is all manual process. Also, I make sure that registered emailId (`myemail@gmail.com`) is also registered in **Verified email list** of **Simple Email Service**

---

**Update:**

I can confirm no matter what, for all users with **Force Change Password**, it sends email to only one non-registered emailId.

Comment: Are you certain the HostedUI you are accessing is connected to the same user pool you are using for adding users? It could be that (if you have multiple pools) you are accidentally mixing up different user pools.

If that isn't the problem, can you recreate the same issue with a totally separate user pool and hosted UI?

Answer (score 0):

When a user is in the FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD state it's not possible to use perform the Forgot Password flow according to [AWS re:Post Knowledge Center](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cognito-forgot-password):

> The user isn't in a CONFIRMED status
>
> Users created by administrators are in a FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD status by default until they sign in with the password provided. Then, users are prompted to change the password.
>
> If the user status is FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD, then the ForgotPassword API call can't be used and the verification code isn't sent.

To avoid user enumeration, when `PreventUserExistenceErrors` is enabled, Cognito answer simulates sending the email/message to a *fictitious* address/number as explained in [Cognito Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-managing-errors.html#cognito-user-pool-managing-errors-password-reset):

> **ForgotPassword**
>
> When a user isn't found, is deactivated, or doesn't have a verified delivery mechanism to recover their password, Amazon Cognito returns CodeDeliveryDetails with a simulated delivery medium for a user.

Disabling `PreventUserExistenceErrors` in the userpool client will show the real error message: `{"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"User password cannot be reset in the current state."}`.